# Flux/utils: How to access to props in the calculateState method?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

In a [container](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html#container) component, how can I get a state from a store in the `calculateState` static method based on `this.props` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***containers cannot access props By default*** containers are not able to access any props. This is both for performance reasons, and to ensure that containers are re-usable and props do not have to be threaded throughout a component tree. There are some valid situations in which you need to determine your state based on both props and a store's state. In those situations **pass options {withProps: true} as the second argument to create(). This will expose the components props as the second argument to calculateState().**

```
  class CounterContainer extends Component {

       static calculateState(prevState,props) {
         return {
           counter: CounterStore.getState(props.id),
        };
      }

        render() {
           return <CounterUI counter={this.state.counter} />;
        }
  }

const container = Container.create(CounterContainer, {withProps:true});
```

Comment: I already defined a `getStateById` method on the store, the problem is that I can't access to `this.props.params.id`  inside the `calculateState` static method for example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the new static function declaration but I guess it instantiates its own scope, let me know if my suggestion works I'm curious

Comment: didn't work, you can't declare `self` like this in the class scope.

Comment: Maybe with a getter ? Updated answer

Comment: you can't access to the getter form the static method, and also, you can't declare `self` in the class scope (syntax method: unexpected token).

Comment: Last suggestion, calling the static method in the render passing the id there. Updated again, let me know what's the result

Comment: Thanks,  I just fired an issue (question) [Here](https://github.com/facebook/flux/issues/275).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88302/discussion-between-tarrsalah-and-francois-richard).